# Characterization of globally lipschitz function in terms of derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lebesgue-measure, lipschitz-functions

I would like to know if the following generalization of the characterization of globally lipschitz functions in the class $\mathcal{C}^1$:

> Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$, $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an interval.
>
> If $f \in \mathcal{C}^1$ then $f$ is globally lipschitz $\iff \exists
>  L \ge 0.\forall t \in I.|f'(t)| \le L$

The generalization goes as follows:

> A scalar function is globally lipschitz iff its derivative exists and is
>   bounded except in a set of measure zero.

Is this still true? Has it been studied/asked before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. The [Cantor-Vitali function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is continuous in $[0,1]$, differentiable almost everywhere with zero derivative, but it is not Lipschitz continuous.